# Laravel Sentry Auth Expired Time

Tags: laravel

How to set expired time for Sentry auth / token?

I Need to set the time to 60 minute or 1 day maybe.

Is it can be set at config? but i don't find the setting for expired time login.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer or include a link to the docs?

Comment: @ehfeng i'm blind about this, when i using sentry and login, after a week i'm still login,  is it good that it's automatically loged out if it's more that a day?

Comment: Have you published the sentry config file? If not, use `php artisan config:publish cartalyst/sentry` to do so

Comment: yes i have sentry at my config folder @Fester

Answer (score 2):

Go to `config\session.php`.

Change the `lifetime` value to any number of minutes. Sentry will use that value as its session expiry time.

As per the laravel documentation:

```
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
```